# How to compare multiple values with each other for a key with in an hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap

I have an hash which looks something like this

```
my %hash = (key1 => [value1],
           key2 => [value1,value2],
           key3 => [value3,value3,value3],
           key4 => [value2,value2,value2]
           );
```

Now I want to compare these values with one other and pick out the odd key.i.e., the key for which all values are not same and in this case it's `key2`
Taking out each key and iterating over arrays seem to be ordeal.Is there an easy way to do that?
I want to use this odd key and print out values/give it a count in an hash
for ex.

```
   my %hash2;
   $hash2{key2}{value1} =2;
   $hash2{key2}{value2} =2;
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't `key` also not a match? How do you determine that they are the same? I think I would use https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep::NoTest for this. Maybe with a `bag` comparison. That seems to be the laziest way I can think of, besides asking strangers on the internet to do it for me. ;)

Comment: @simbabque,The values in this case are strings so I think we can use `eq` operator  would prefer code instead of modules

Comment: Modules are code. This looks a lot like a homework question to be honest. If that is the case, study the code of that module. It will help you understand what you need to do. And please explain the goal you have a little bit better. Your second code block is not very clear. I don't understand why you assign these numbers. And what about `key1`?

Comment: I think that "Taking out each key and iterating over arrays" is the only way to do so. Maybe `grep` could be useful, it's a *maybe* I didn't try anything on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @odd_keys;

my %hash = (key1 => [1],
            key2 => [1,2],
            key3 => [3,3,3],
            key4 => [2,2,2]
           );

foreach my $key (keys(%hash))
{
  #builds an array with every cell equal to first cell 
  my @temp_array = grep {$_ eq $hash{$key}->[0]} @{$hash{$key}};
  #if the size of this array is different than the size of array associated to key, that means that all values are not equal
  if (@temp_array != @{$hash{$key}})
  {
    print "$key\n"; 
    push(@odd_keys, $key);
  }
}
```

prints odd keys and creates an @odd_keys array

Comment: for some reason it only works when values are numerical, doesn't work when it's a string(combination of alphabets and numerical)

Comment: true, that's because of the `==` that compares numbers, to compare strings you have to use `eq`

Comment: @sarahJ edit: in fact, replacing `==` with `eq` will work for numerical values too, fixed the code ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me out

Answer (score 2):

In order to find your key of interest you can filter for those values that have more than one unique element. For `uniq` you can either use [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) or if you want to avoid modules you can define the function yourself ([explanation here](https://perlmaven.com/unique-values-in-an-array-in-perl))

```
sub uniq {
  my %seen;
  return grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @_;
}
```

You can then filter the keys like this:

```
# get an array of pairs of "uniq count" and "key"
my @key_counts = map {[uniq(@{$hash{$_}})+0, $_]} keys %hash;
# filter this array for those with "uniq count" greater than 1 and only keep key
my @keys_of_interest = map {$_->[1]} grep {$_->[0] > 1} @key_counts;
# if you know that there is only a single key of interest
my $key = $keys_of_interest[0];
```

You can use this `$key` and the corresponding `value` to get your `%hash2`:

```
my %hash2;
$hash2{$key}{$_} = 2 foreach(@{$hash{$key}});
```

Comment: Hello! Have you considered joining us at a German Perl Workshop or another Perl conference?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me.It worked perfectly.